# Flask-Admin: How to prevent deletion of inline_models?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I'm trying to prevent the deletion of certain entries in the inline model views with `flask-admin`:

[image]

The respective inline model code looks like this:

```
class ModelCategoryValueInline(InlineFormAdmin):
    form_columns = ('id', 'display_name', 'name')
    form_edit_columns = ('id', 'display_name')
    can_delete = False
    form_args= dict(
        display_name=dict(label='Display Name', validators=[DataRequired()]),
        name=dict(label='Technical Name', validators=[DataRequired()]),
    )

    def on_model_delete(self, model):
        # Not called at all..
        print('on_model_delete', model)
        if model.builtin == True:
            raise ValidationError(f'[{model}] is a build-in CategoryValue and cannot be deleted.') 
        
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        # Is called, but has model already changed... - deleted models do not get this event
        if not is_created:
            if form.form.name.data != model.name:
                raise ValidationError(f'You cannot change the internal name of a category value!')     
               
    def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
        # not called att all
        form.name.render_kw = {'disabled': 'disabled', 'readonly': True}
```

I haven't figured out a way to prevent deletion of inline entries. `on_model_delete()` is not called when deleting the inline entries. `can_delete` has no effect either.

How can I disable the deletion of inline entries?

Ideally I want to be able to control deletion via the `on_model_delete()` method and prevent only deletion of values that match certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use something similar to

```py
class NoDeleteInlineModelFormList(InlineModelFormList):
    def display_row_controls(self, field):
        return False

class NoDeleteInlineModelConverter(InlineModelConverter):
    inline_field_list_type = NoDeleteInlineModelFormList

class ParentView(sqla.ModelView):
    inline_models = [Child]
    inline_model_form_converter = NoDeleteInlineModelConverter
```

You can find more details at my repo https://github.com/mapio/Flask-Admin-Inline-Models-And-Related-Fields

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is not an ideal solution I've managed to achieve the desired behaviour by editing the `inline_list_base.html` template:

```
{% macro render_inline_fields(field, template, render, check=None) %}
<div class="inline-field" id="{{ field.id }}">
    {# existing inline form fields #}
    <div class="inline-field-list">
        {% for subfield in field %}
        <div id="{{ subfield.id }}" class="inline-field well well-sm">
            {%- if not check or check(subfield) %}
            <legend>
                <small>
                    {{ field.label.text }} #{{ loop.index }}
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        {% if subfield.get_pk and subfield.get_pk() %}

                        # Added if statement to check if field is builtin and disable checkbox
                        {% if subfield.object_data.builtin %} 
                            <label for="del-{{ subfield.id }}" style="display: inline"><i title="This is a built-in value and cannot be deleted" data-toggle="tooltip">Built-in</i></label>
                        {% else %}
                            <input type="checkbox" name="del-{{ subfield.id }}" id="del-{{ subfield.id }}" />
                            <label for="del-{{ subfield.id }}" style="display: inline">{{ _gettext('Delete?') }}</label>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" value="{{ _gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this record?') }}" class="inline-remove-field"><i class="fa fa-times glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </small>
            </legend>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            {%- endif -%}
            {{ render(subfield) }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {# template for new inline form fields #}
    <div class="inline-field-template hide">
        {% filter forceescape %}
        <div class="inline-field well well-sm">
            <legend>
                <small>{{ _gettext('New') }} {{ field.label.text }}</small>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" value="{{ _gettext('Are you sure you want to delete this record?') }}" class="inline-remove-field"><span class="fa fa-times glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </div>
            </legend>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            {{ render(template) }}
        </div>
        {% endfilter %}
    </div>
    <a id="{{ field.id }}-button" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default" onclick="faForm.addInlineField(this, '{{ field.id }}');">{{ _gettext('Add') }} {{ field.label.text }}</a>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

When placing this file in `templates/admin/model/inline_list_base.html` this has the desired effect and prevents the user from deleting certain fields:

[image]

I would want to have a check also at the backend but I haven't found a solution for that yet.